# Laravel 5 clause WHERE with AND OR AND?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

How do i say:

```
WHERE (login = 'login_1' and date_creation BETWEEN 'date1' AND 'date2') 
    OR (login = 'login_1' and date_creation = 'null') 
    OR (date_creation BETWEEN 'date1' AND 'date2' and login = 'null')
```

I would like to use it in laravel.

I try with this code :

```
->where('login',"=",'login_1')  
->orWhereBetween('date_creation', array('date1', 'date2'))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that best option is to do it like this:

```
->where(function($query) {
    $query->where('login', 'login_1')
    $query->whereBetween('date_creation', 'date1', 'date2')
})
->orWhere(function($query) {
    $query->where('login', 'login_1')
    $query->whereNull('date_creation')
})
->orWhere(function($query) {
    $query->whereNull('login')
    $query->whereBetween('date_creation', 'date1', 'date2')
});
```